# Problem with [variable] changing all inputs in a NgFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I am building a table which has a priority field and a percentage field.

I am working with a webcomponent, which has an input. This input will change according to the "state" priority, which can be "error" or "success".
The problem is I am building a table which has a priority field and a percentage field. When the percentage field exceeds 100% it should change to the state "error" else "success"

The problem I am having is that once a percentage field exceeds 100%, it works correctly, but it is also changing the other priorities, **I only need to chenge the inputs that belong to the same priority to the "error" state.**

As you can see in the example, I have two different priorities (1 and 3), when I exceed 100% of the priority, I should only change the input to priority 1, not priority 3

EXAMPLE: [Example Gift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9icu.gif)

How can i fix this?

html:

```
          <ds-table-body-row slot="row" *ngFor="let detail of beneficiarios; let i = index">
              <ds-table-body-column slot="column">
                <span slot="element">
                  <ds-paragraph type="p2" family="primary" weight="regular" color="primary">
                    <span slot="text" class=""
                      >{{detail.Priority}}
                    </span>
                  </ds-paragraph>
                </span>
              </ds-table-body-column>
              <ds-table-body-column slot="column">
                <span slot="element">
                  <ds-paragraph id = "tett" type="p2" family="primary" weight="regular" color="primary">
                    <span slot="text" class=""
                      > <ds-input
                      size="s1"
                      value="{{detail.Percent}}"
                      initial-label= ""
                      labelOrientation="start"
                      [state] = "invalidPercent"
                      (focusout)="focusOutPercent(i, $event.target.value)"
                      helperMessage='test'>
                      </ds-input>
                    </span>
                  </ds-paragraph>
                </span>
              </ds-table-body-column>
          </ds-table-body-row>
```

ts:

```
invalidPercent:any;
  focusOutPercent(i: number, percentAdded:any){
    this.beneficiarios[i].Percent = percentAdded
    let total = 0;
    let sum =  i + 1;
    this.beneficiarios.forEach(i => {
      if(Number(i.Priority) == sum){
        total += Number(i.Percent)
        if (total > 100) {
          this.invalidPercent = "error";
        }else{
          this.invalidPercent = "success";
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your invalidPercent is a single var and all your fields depend on it. The easiest solution is to change your beneficarios' items to have their own invalidPercent property and use in html and check in ypur method just that - individual detail.invalidPercent

Comment: hi Misha, can u help with that, i dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, preferrably when you get `beneficarios`, add new property in the loop:

```
this.beneficiarios.forEach(item => {
    item.invalidPercent = 'success';
})
```

In your `focusOutPercent` method change:

```
if (total > 100) {
     this.invalidPercent = "error";
} else {
     this.invalidPercent = "success";
}
```

To:

```
if (total > 100) {
     i.invalidPercent = "error";
} else {
     i.invalidPercent = "success";
}
```

And then in your html template change:

`[state] = "invalidPercent"`

to

`[state] = "detail.invalidPercent"`

Comment: Micha, its working well, but The problem is that if, for example, I put 110 in the first field, it will be marked in red, but I also need the other elements that share the same priority to be put in red, even if their value is below 100. That is, if any element of a priority is above 100, all elements of that priority must be marked in red

Comment: Can you give an example of `beneficiarios` array of objects? And do you mean that when two or more `detail` items have the same `Priority`, they should have the same `invalidPercentage`?

Comment: can i show my code in real time? by discord or something?